# Geometry of recently created point

Tags: pyqgis, geometry, code-review, forms

#### Description

I am currently working on a project that requires the creation of default values in certain fields when attempting to insert a new feature. This operation is illustrated in the figure below.

For this task, I am using PyQGIS 3.28.

#### Problem

As depicted in the image below, there is a field labeled ID_PM (string). In order for this field to receive a default value, it must be within a polygon layer named ZAPM.

If the point does not fall within any polygon, the attributes form should close, and an error message should be displayed to the user.

#### Requirements

- Retrieve the geometry of the inserted point
- Check if the point is located within the polygon layer
- If the point's geometry is not within the polygon layer, close the attributes form
- If the point's geometry is within the polygon layer, change the default field value

#### Code

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsDefaultValue

layername = "PM"
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layername)[0]


def fiels_to_text_edit(layer,field,value):
    config =  {'IsMultiline': False, 'UseHtml': False}
    layer.editFormConfig().setWidgetConfig("TextEdit", config)
    default_value = QgsDefaultValue()
    default_value.setExpression(f"'{value}'")
    field_index = layer.fields().indexFromName(field)
    
    # Set the default value for the specific field
    layer.setDefaultValueDefinition(field_index, default_value)


layer_nro = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("NRO")[0]
features = layer_nro.getFeatures()
first_feature = next(features)
ref_nro_value = first_feature["REF_NRO"]
g2r = first_feature["G2R_NRO"]


layer_commune = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("FT_Commune")[0]
features = layer_commune.getFeatures()
first_feature = next(features)
commune = first_feature["NOM"]


fiels_to_text_edit(layer, "REF_NRO",ref_nro_value)
fiels_to_text_edit(layer, "COMMUNE",commune)
fiels_to_text_edit(layer, "G2R",g2r)
```

Any flaw in my code, feel free to correct it.

[image]

#### Edit

So for now, I learned that the point is not yet created even when inserted in map, first the form shows up and then after submiting the form, it will appear.

In the images below you can see what I'm talking. In the first image (before) the point is not in map yet, but form is showing up and after submiting the form, the point appears.

Is there no possible way to get the point geometry when the form show up (Before image)?

**Image Before:**

[image: Before]

**Image After:**

[image: After]

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I don't know how to get the geom of an inserted point.
I can't do `feature.geometry()` because the point is not created, is in the **process** of being created.

Comment: What is the type ID_PM?  The answer to this question seems to hinge on knowing what it is. My first guess is that it is a single 1-D value which is hard to ask if it is inside a polygon.

Comment: Type ID_PM is String.
But for now what I want it to get the `geometry` when the form show up.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your 'inserted point' is created by adding a feature during editing, you can access the last added feature from the edit buffer like so:

```py
lyr = iface.activeLayer()

# reference the current edit buffer
edit_buffer = lyr.editBuffer()

# get features added since last commit (returns a dict)
added_features = edit_buffer.addedFeatures()

# get a list of the added features
added_features_list = list(added_features.values())

# sort the list of features by their id and get the first element (lowest id)
last_added = sorted(added_features_list, key=lambda f: f.id())[0]

print(last_added.id(), last_added.geometry().asPoint())

# >>> -20 <QgsPointXY: POINT(-25.49059674901456418 37.77884306286578209)>
```

Features in the edit buffer (created but not yet saved) receive a negative id, which decreases for each successive feature added. Therefore, the lowest id is the last feature to be added.